# How to auto load a tab content (external link) on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tabs

I'm using the jquery tabs tool (http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax.html) to load tab content with ajax. When I load the page, the first tab (as can be seen on the demo on the address above) is blank. You have to click another tab and then click the first tab again to load the external page. Is there a way to load the external link in the first tab on page load?

Apologies in advance, I am not a coder but I've already tried multiple 'fixes' posted elsewhere online and to no avail (though its possible I'm not implementing them correctly!). I'm not 100% what code is needed or where to put it

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your link, in that standalone demo: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax.htm  there is 'nothing' in the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

You would surely like this one

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax-noeffect.htm

and try this code, I havnt tried it but you.

```
 //Replace your this line of code
 $("ul.css-tabs").tabs("div.css-panes > div", {effect: 'ajax'});

 //WIth this code
 $("ul.css-tabs").tabs("div.css-panes > div", {
    effect: 'fade',
    onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
    var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);
    if (pane.is(":empty")) {
        pane.load(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("href"));
    }
    }
  });
```

Let me know if that worked. I don't why but I had shut down and packed my laptop but just to reply you I turned on my laptop and posted it.